# elasticsearch won't start because it can't find java 8

Tags: java, elasticsearch, java-8

I'm trying to run an instance of elasticsearch version 1.8 on an ubuntu machine.
When i elasticsearch I get:

```
es@ubuntu-mwa-flask:/root/elasticsearch-5.4.0$ ./bin/elasticsearch
Error: Could not find or load main class org.elasticsearch.tools.JavaVersionChecker
Elasticsearch requires at least Java 8 but your Java version from /usr/bin/java does not meet this requirement
```

I've checked which java version I have:

```
es@ubuntu-mwa-flask:/root/elasticsearch-5.4.0$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

What am I doing wrong? I've installed elasticsearch on afew machines before, why doesn't this one work?

edit1: since someone asked:

```
es@ubuntu-mwa-flask:/root/elasticsearch-5.4.0$ /usr/bin/java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
mixed mode)
```

edit2:

```
es@ubuntu-mwa-flask:/root/elasticsearch-5.4.0$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_131
```

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/java -version`?

Comment: I added the result, it's the same as java -version

Comment: And `echo $JAVA_HOME`? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html

Comment: Also, did you just download the `tar`? Why didn't you use `apt-get`? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

Comment: Did you have `javac`? Let's try to check `javac -version`

Comment: @cricket_007 this way I get to see the errors more easily.

Comment: @Tuyen Nguyen I added the javac -version, it's 1.8

Comment: Did you try the solution from [this post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/installation-in-error-solved/81977/9)

Comment: @TuyenNguyen The server won't start, so why would curl-ing the server do anything?

Comment: @SnelleJelle The errors are displayed the same in `/var/log`

Comment: The [post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/installation-in-error-solved/81977) is have the same problem with @SnelleJelle. Please read it from start, the link I post above is from the end, sorry for that

Comment: @tuyen Nguyen yes, apparantly I have to run es as owner of the entire folder. what a silly thing, but it works now! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't have right permissions. Try to set them to 774 and check again:

```
sudo chmod 774 -R elasticsearch-6.3.2/
```